# How to process saml:Assertion in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

New to WCF, but very familiar with past WSE* paradigms. I'm finding the configurability (read: complexities) of WCF to be quite a challenge.

I'm attempting to use a .NET 4.0 WCF Client to consume a web service provided by our government which runs on WebSphere Application Server/6.1.

Their scheme uses a UsernameToken to authenticate and exchange for a SAML Assertion over HTTPS transport encryption. This SAML Assertion is used for the remainder of the opertations with their services.

When attempting to "Login" (i.e. acquire the SAML Assertion), I'm getting the following exception from WCF when it attempts to process the return SOAP:

**"Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SamlSecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings."**

Here's my settings file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Default"
            contract="ServiceProxy.Login"
            name="Login" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Default">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here's the SOAP request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <!-- Removed -->
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="c9363270-1b33-4ffe-90b0-427feebcebf6" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">cadd6a3c-7b36-46eb-9130-390227effc08</ActivityId>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2012-12-13T22:50:22.308Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2012-12-13T22:55:22.308Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-91607d82-da2c-4004-93b6-baf5973ba057-1">
        <o:Username>
          <!-- Removed-->
        </o:Username>
        <o:Password>
          <!-- Removed-->
        </o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <LoginRequest xmlns="http://snipped.url/Services.xsd"></LoginRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And here's the response that makes WCF choke:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <!-- Removed -->
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:mustUnderstand="1">
        <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" AssertionID="id-94ef81a2eba3b246e284f72c3313e32ababe9482" IssueInstant="2012-12-13T22:50:23.930Z" Issuer="http://www.forumsys.com/sentry" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1">
          <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2012-12-13T22:50:23.930Z" NotOnOrAfter="2012-12-14T08:50:23.930Z"></saml:Conditions>
          <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant="2012-12-13T22:50:23.930Z" AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password">
            <saml:Subject>
              <saml:NameIdentifier>
                <!-- Removed-->
              </saml:NameIdentifier>
              <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:sender-vouches</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
              </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:SubjectLocality>
              <!-- Removed-->
            </saml:SubjectLocality>
          </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
          <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Subject>
              <saml:NameIdentifier>
                <!-- Removed-->
              </saml:NameIdentifier>
              <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:sender-vouches</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
              </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            </saml:Subject>
            <saml:Attribute AttributeName="SMSESSION" AttributeNamespace="http://www.forumsys.com/sentry">
              <saml:AttributeValue>
                <!-- Removed-->
              </saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
          </saml:AttributeStatement>
          </saml:Assertion>
        <u:Timestamp xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" u:Id="_0">
          <u:Created>2012-12-13T22:50:22.308Z</u:Created>
          <u:Expires>2012-12-13T22:55:22.308Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <o:UsernameToken xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" u:Id="uuid-91607d82-da2c-4004-93b6-baf5973ba057-1">
          <o:Username>
            <!-- Removed-->
          </o:Username>
          <o:Password>
            <!-- Removed-->
          </o:Password>
        </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <wn1:LoginResponse xmlns:wn1="http://snipped.url/Services.xsd">
        <wn1:Status>session counter updated</wn1:Status>
      </wn1:LoginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above response is a successful response and matches prior versions running on WSE2/3 (which for other reasons I'm unable to use going forward).

How do I get WCF to acknowledge the above response as valid? Or perhaps just to get it to ignore the fact that it can't parse it and I can manually parse it perhaps.

I'm stumped!

**UPDATE #1:**

I started to go down the Custom Client credentials route. This seemed promising, if a bit complicated.

If you want to go this route...

1) See MS article series here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868(v=vs.100).aspx

2) Also see WCF Samples WCF\Extensibility\Security\SamlTokenProvider.

3) Blog post using this method: http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2011/11/this-has-been-hanging-around-in-my.html

This should allow you to use SAML Assertions without WIF.

**UPDATE #2:**

See my answer and ultimate solution below.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, so that you can get upvotes, and so that future readers can find it more easily.

Comment: Hmmm. Technically Yaron gave the answer, which I accepted, I just detailed the final solution in my OP. If I do what you suggest, wouldn't that apply the points to me instead of Yaron? (Not very familiar with how SO does that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that in order to get the saml don't use wcf security. simply add the username to the request via a custom header (probably with message inspector) and use the same method to extract the SAML from the response. Then in the same way push the saml to each further envelope.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. Added more details in the original post for others.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately went with Yaron's suggestion and wrote a couple custom inspectors & behaviors.

Using proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName/Password was the cause of the original exception reported above. It would try and validate the return SOAP before processing subsequent added behaviors, resulting in response validation errors on the SAML assertion every time.

The first behavior/inspector has two jobs:

1) In the request side, manually add UsernameToken nodes;

2) In the response side, extract the saml token; be sure to remove any offending "Security" XML nodes from the SOAP and reprocess the reply (prevents another error like the original post); save the SAML response for later.

The second behavior/inspector injects the shared SAML assertion into the remainder of the requests.

Here's the config required:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Default">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Here's some code (notice the removal of the ClientCredentials behavior):

```
var proxy = new LoginClient();
proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
var initLogin = new InitialLoginMessageBehavior("username", "password");
proxy.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(initLogin);
var response = proxy.Login();

//use the SAML response
var proxy2 = new OtherClient();
proxy2.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<ClientCredentials>();
proxy2.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SamlAuthenticationMessageBehavior(initLogin.Saml));

var response2 = proxy2.DoSomethingElse();
```

Everything you need for creating behaviors and inspectors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.100).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx